# ionrangeSlider Nuxt Vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, ion-range-slider

I'm new in Nuxt and I'm trying to use a jquery library "ionrangeSlider" but I get an error:

```
$(...).ionRangeSlider is not a function
```

I ran `npm i ion-rangeslider` and I add the vendor in my nuxt.config.js:

```
build: {
    vendor: [
      "jquery",
      "ion-rangeslider"
    ],
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
      })
    ],
  },
```

And in my component I have:

```
mounted(){
   var that = this;
   this.$nextTick(function(){
      $(that.$refs.range).ionRangeSlider();
    },
}
```

I think that nuxt doesn't compile correcty the library from node_modules, but I don't know what I can do :(